# getMax Method to get the bigger number

Tags: java

I'm a noob to Java & I got stuck on a problem.

So the assignment is like this

> There is one method required:  getMax, which takes two integer variables as input, returns >the bigger one of the two. Your main method must look like the following (except the comment.

```
main( String[] args)
{   
     int num1, num2;
     num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
     num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
     System.out.println(“the bigger value of the two is : “ + getMax(num1, num2));
}
```

You program may work like:

java Assign5 23 67

the bigger value of the two is 67

After a little struggle here is the little program I wrote.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//use getMax to takes two numbers and returns bigger of the two

public class assignment5 {
        private static void getMax(int a, int b ){
            Scanner kevin = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter First Number:");
        a = kevin.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Second Number:");
        b = kevin.nextInt();

    getMax(a, b); if (a > b) {
        System.out.println(a + " is bigger"); }
    else {
        System.out.println(b + " is bigger");
        }

    }

    }
```

but this is somehow very different from the actual assignment. I feel a bit stupid. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

You went in a wrong direction.

You tried to change the read mecanism of the two int whereas this part was given.

When you look at the exercise source, you see that the code calls "getMax(num1, num2)", which is not implemented. So, you have to implement a method with this signature:

```
public int getMax(int num1, int num2) {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int getMax(int a, int b) {
  return (a>b?a:b);
}
```

What happens if the numbers are equal?

Comment: You shouldn't give out the answer like that, he asked for help on his homework. We should help him by helping him learn not giving the answer.

Comment: Sorry, completely right about this, but I figured the guy had done a lot to learn about Scanner, and was barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the example you have been given.  The code to read the input is already in the `main(String[] args)` method.  Since your instructor has been kind enough to give you this part of the solution, use it.  Programmers are always looking for ways to avoid re-inventing the wheel.  Copying other people's working code is a good way to do that.

Now look at the line in your instructor's code where the actual work is done:

```
System.out.println("the bigger value of the two is : " + getMax(num1, num2));
```

This code is calling a method, `getMax(num1, num2)`.

Your instructor should have told you how to write your own methods.  You will need to do that here.  Think about what type value your method will return.  Think about what it will have to do internally to determine which of its two parameters, `num1` and `num2` is larger.

Write that method, put it into your `Assignment5` class in the right place and test it.  Always test your code.  Untested code will fail and get lower marks.

When you have tested it and it is working correctly you can hand it in.

Answer (score 0):

- Include your `main` method in your `assignment5` class such that it can be executed as required
- Make your `getMax` so that it only returns `a` or `b` (the larger one) which it gets as input from your main method

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a lot of things to fix. First your getMax method is not well written (the way your main method is written you'll need to return the number and not just print a string):

```
public static int getMax(a, b){
    if (a > b) {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Next thing you need to declare your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int num1, num2;
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    System.out.println(“the bigger value of the two is : “ + getMax(num1, num2));
}
```

`args[0]` et `args[1]` means that you have to give the numbers when you start your program and not wait for the user to enter them. When you'll launch your program, for example from your command line, it will look like this:

```
java -jar programname 23 54
```

or you can also specify your number in the run arguments if you use eclipse

Comment: You also can't invoke your non-static getMax() method from main()